# How to pass system property "javax.net.ssl.keyStore" as argument to gradle bootRun (Gradle 7.4)

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, bootrun

I'm struggling to get this to work.

This below works fine:

```
./gradlew bootRun --args="--spring.profiles.active=dev"
```

But, all these below don't seem to work to pass in `javax.net.ssl.keyStore`, unless I'm mistaken in my testing.

```
./gradlew bootRun --args="--spring.profiles.active=dev --javax.net.ssl.keyStore=/file"

./gradlew bootRun --args="--spring.profiles.active=dev --Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=/file"

./gradlew bootRun --args="--spring.profiles.active=dev -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=/file"

./gradlew bootRun -Dspring.profiles.active=dev -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=/file
```

I'd like to avoid modifying the task in `build.gradle` and need the system properties to be passed in as command line arguments.

Answer (score 0):

What about of

-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=file:/your_file_path

Comment: Still doesn't work.  It just seems there's no way to pass system properties via command line with grandle at the moment (apart from spring.profiles.active).